Crystal report : show the the rows even if the colmns are null
I am trying to make my cross tab show the lines even if the columns are empty;
The cross tab model is the following:
Day_of_month brand1 brand2
day_1         1
day_2               3
total_month   1     3

The current behavior is If a given month does not have brand sales (total is null) it simply does not show the cross tab, and I want to print the left part consisting of the days of the month even if no sale is made.

Create a DATES table with one row for each date. Outer Join from the DATES table to your data.
That would ensure the CrossTab contains all the days of the month.

Can it be done in a crow tab with data source from xml ?
